# PHP Check if POST method contains one of values

Tags: php, arrays, post

can you please help me with a such issue:
I need to check, if in array, which is passed in $_POST contains some specific value, and if yes - does some stuff.. currently I have:

```
$count=count($_POST['prcategory']);
if(implode($_POST['prcategory']) == "'Cost Collection'" && $count=1 ){
  ...do stuff
}
elseif (implode($_POST['prcategory']) == "'Cost Collection'" && $count > 1 )
{
  ...do other stuff
}
else {.... }
```

But for the unknown for me reason, when the count is >1, it always goes to the last else option - most probably, it's because I'm not aware, how to properly check, if one of POST values contains my needed value ..

Any suggestions on this?

p.s. all values are passed in quotes, e.g. it's fine, that I have quotes in : 'Cost Collection'

Comment: compare with `$count == 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**use simple if else**

NOTE : $_POST['prcategory'] should be an array() other wise in_array will not work

```
    if(isset($_POST['prcategory'])) {
     $count = count($_POST['prcategory']);
     $data = $_POST[prcategory];
     if (in_array("'Cost Collection'", $data)) { // 'Cost Collection' is the value to check in array $data u can use any value
            if ($count == 0 ) {
                //do stuff.......

            }elseif($count > 1)  {
                  //do stuff.......

            }else {
                //do stuff.......
            }

     }else {
            //do stuff.......
          }
   }
```

Comment: he says his post data has literal quotes in it, so it should be `"'Cost Collection'"`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about in_array function, now it works perfectly!

Comment: my Pleasure glad to help you , happy coding

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(isset($_POST['prcategory']))
{
   // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Hi, isset is not needed on the step I'm into, reply lower helped with in_array function.